# ASP.NET TextBox - jQuery Counter function not being fired

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, character, counter

I have a jquery function that should count characters the user is typing in ASP.NET textbox. This information will appear on:

```
<span ID="remaining" class="label">160 characters remaining</span>
<span ID="messages" class="msgleft">1 message(s)</span>   

The jQUery function is shown below:

 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var $remaining = $('#remaining'),
        $messages = $remaining.next();

            $('#messagetext').keyup(function () {
                var chars = this.value.length,
            messages = Math.ceil(chars / 160),
            remaining = messages * 160 - (chars % (messages * 160) || messages * 160);

                $remaining.text(remaining + ' characters remaining');
                $messages.text(messages + ' message(s)');
            });
        });
</script>
```

The ID of the ASP.NET Textbox is messagetext but jQuery function/event is not being fired. When I use HTML text area it works fine. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
   //.net dynamic ClientID
   $('#<% = messagetext.ClientID %>').keyup(function () {
            var chars = this.value.length,
        messages = Math.ceil(chars / 160),
        remaining = messages * 160 - (chars % (messages * 160) || messages * 160);

            $remaining.text(remaining + ' characters remaining');
            $messages.text(messages + ' message(s)');
        });
```

or

```
   //jquery input id wildcard selector
   $("input:[id*=messagetext]").keyup(function () {
            var chars = this.value.length,
        messages = Math.ceil(chars / 160),
        remaining = messages * 160 - (chars % (messages * 160) || messages * 160);

            $remaining.text(remaining + ' characters remaining');
            $messages.text(messages + ' message(s)');
        });
```

Comment: Thank you Rick, the first option worked great. I appreciate your help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, worked. I had to make a slight change to this:

```
$("[id$=messagetxt]").keyup(function () {
        var chars = this.value.length,
    messages = Math.ceil(chars / 160),
    remaining = messages * 160 - (chars % (messages * 160) || messages * 160);
        $('input[id=remaining]').val(remaining + ' characters remaining');
        $('input[id=messages]').val(messages + ' message(s)');
    });
```